# Adobe Flash beginner: error 1009

Tags: flash

I'm trying to make a flash website sort of thing for the Up movie.

I have some buttons linking to a movie click, that will then go to a picture gallery. that is all in mc_content, and placed on the stage, instance name content_mc. inside mc_content i have an actions layer and a content layer that has mc_gallery that is labelled as gallery.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

gallery_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onGalleryClick);

function onGalleryClick(evt:MouseEvent): void {
trace("gallery");
content_mc.gotoAndStop("gallery");
}
```

gallery is the label where mc_gallery is located in mc_content.

When I run it it gets a 1009 error code.

I'm guessing this is a very easy fix, and there are alot of answers already posted, but I just can't figure out how to adapt it to my needs. I have the code identical to another project i succesfully

Answer (score 0):

The 1009 error is stating that it can't access to the properties of a null object reference.

What it basically says is that something you're trying to use is actually null, thus non-existent.

Try to check your instances names, properties and variable, to be sure they're correctly named and properly initialized before being used (for small example, are your sure content_mc is the right name of your MovieClip on the stage ?...)

It would be very difficult for us to solve your problem with so little code, as such error can be hidden everywhere ! :-)

But if the error pops when you click on your button, it could say that the problem is either the

```
content_mc.gotoAndStop("gallery");
```

line, or is situated at your *gallery* label in your content_mc MovieClip.